# Use a custom usercontrol in a Janus GridEx

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2005, janus, gridex

I'm search for a method to add a custom usercontrol in a Janus GridEx with C#. In the designer I have different columntypes (link, text, image, ...) but I need something with more functionality (multiple checkboxes which must be set/saved in a seperate table).

I think this would be easiest if I could just add a custom component I can build by myself.

Any ideas if this is possible and how to do this?

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. You can create a custom control that inherets from UserControl. Then, set the column type to Text and the EditType to Custom.

You then need to hook up onto the grids InitCustomEdit and EndCustomEdit events where you will perform the custom control logic.